# PHP exec() jar java file not return any output

Tags: java, php, jar, exec

I have a jar file to convert Crystal Report into PDF, i was already  run it on console and its succeed.

When i run it on console.

```
D:\report>java -jar PrintResumePDF.jar
The PDF is created!!.
```

But when i try to run in with exec in PHP, its not giving any result in the output. Even though the PDF file is created or converting process is success.

Here my PHP code:

```
<?php 
   exec("java -jar PrintResumePDF.jar 2>&1", $return);
   print_r($return);
?>
```

The Output of java/jar : **The PDF is created!!** not printed on PHP, its just blank page. Sorry for my broken english, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this is a useful answer to you, but I can't replicate this on PHP7.2 with any arbitrary commands which produce output, so your PHP code at least is likely to be correct.

Eg this code:

```
<?php
// Stderr
exec("curl --aaa 2>&1", $return1);
print_r($return1);
// Stdout
exec("echo hello", $return2);
print_r($return2);
```

Outputs this:

```
$ php foo.php 

Array
(
    [0] => curl: option --aaa: is unknown
    [1] => curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
)
Array
(
    [0] => hello
)
```

I can only suggest checking any relevant logs and/or redirecting the output to a temp file, because if the command executes correctly, then it is plainly either not printing anything from this execution environment, or you're dropping the output elsewhere.

Comment: thx i understand right now with your explanation,
the problem is i must echo the exec,
thx for your helping man